# How serialise/de-serialise an object with Kryo by using an interface

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

Is it possible to serialise/de-serialise an object with Kryo by registering an interface instead of a concreate class?

In concreate I need to serialise a Java 7 `Path` object which is defined as in interface.

I tried writing a serialiser that saves the path URI as a string and recreates it during the read deserialisation. But it turns out the my serialise writer method is never invoked by Kryo.

This is my (Groovy) code:

```
class PathSerializer extends FieldSerializer<Path> {

    PathSerializer(Kryo kryo) {
        super(kryo, Path)
    }

    public void write (Kryo kryo, Output output, Path path) {
        def uri = path.toUri().toString()
        kryo.writeObject(output, uri)
    }

    public Path read (Kryo kryo, Input input, Class<Path> type) {
        def uri = kryo.readObject(input,String)
        Paths.get(new URI(uri))
    }
}

def kryo = new Kryo()
kryo.register(Path, new PathSerializer(kryo))

def path = Paths.get('hola')
Output output = new Output(new FileOutputStream("file.bin"));
kryo.writeObject(output, path);
output.close();
```

Any idea how to register an interface for serialization with Kryo?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `addDefaultSerializer` method:

```
kryo.addDefaultSerializer(Path, new PathSerializer(kryo))
```