# How to implement a KryoSerializer for an interface where all implementing classes are private?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kryo, scala-reflect

I'm trying to write a class to implement `KryoSerializer` so that I can serialize objects for use with Spark.  The issue I'm having is that while all of the classes implement a public interface, all of the implementing classes are private.  Kryo doesn't seem to want to allow me to define a serializer for either a private out-of-package class or an interface.

The way this issue manifests is that when I attempt to define the `KryoSerializer` class, I get an error that `class [implementation] in package graph cannot be accessed in package [same package]`.

What I'm hoping someone can help with, is a strategy for solving this issue.

I understand the reasons why Kryo wants to serialize and deserialize concrete objects. But, in this case, since I am defining my own `KryoSerializer` anyway, it actually would make more sense to define serialization for the interface.  Is there a way to trick Kryo into doing the right thing?

(The reason this will work, is that there is a related `Object` that has functions to take an instance with the interface and write or read from a stream. My serializer would essentially wrap those functions while adding some serialization format version information.)

One possibility I thought of is the reflection trick. When deserializing a class with private/final members, we sometimes use reflection to make the private member accessible and writable, set the value, then set it back to private/final.  I'm not sure if its possible to do that for a private class in another packager, but even if it is, it seems rather ugly and inefficient.

Another possibility would be to define new classes that extend the private classes, along with a set of implicits to convert among them. That would also be rather ugly though, for a few reasons, and there are quite a few private classes at issue.

Can anyone suggest an approach?  Advise regarding pitfalls I should avoid?

Comment: Are you using `setDefaultSerializer` for the interface? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076136/how-serialise-de-serialise-an-object-with-kryo-by-using-an-interface

Comment: That was actually the first thing I tried.  I created a `KryoRegistrator` and passed it to the `SparkContext` using `setLocalProperty`.  Running it from the console, it compiles, but when I try to actually serialize anything, I get `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 15.0 in stage 125.0 (TID 164169) had a not serializable result: [name of concrete class]`.  Its possible that's because I used `setLocalProperty` instead of `SparkConf`.  But I'm trying to implement this in an environment where the `SparkContext` will always be created before my code runs.

Comment: I haven't used `setLocalProperty`, but looking at documentation it's only supposed to be used for specific properties (or if you want to define your own _thread-local_ property). I don't see any reason to expect setting _this_ property with `setLocalProperty` to work.

Comment: Actually it says it's useful for activities in your own thread and jobs launched from the running thread.

Comment: Just search for `"spark.kryo.registrator"` in the source, and you'll see it's only looked up from `conf`, not from `localProperties`.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're seeing that in the source, but I believe you!  That's what I suspected was going on.  But it doesn't really resolve my question because I'm trying to implement this in an environment where the SparkContext will always be created before my code runs.